# Turn off the keypad sound from my application settings

Tags: android, android-keypad

I want add a settings in my app which will let the user to turn the keypad volume on or off. I don't know whether it's possible to made the settings from my app? If yes then how? I didn't find any links that describes such example? can anybody help me out of this please?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are a phones out there which play the keypad sound on their own. In this case, it seems to not be possible to disable the keypad sound.